# detecting competing CPU use and multiprocessing.manager helper process PID

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pid

Is there a recommended way to access the PID of the helper process that's spawned when `manager=multiprocessing.Manager()` is called, so I can establish a complete list of PIDs related to my Python application?

I have a Python application that I want to run on a resource-constrained embedded linux host. The host OS is stripped down but some yet-to-be-identified foreign process is infrequently and irregularly consuming a lot of CPU which is adversely impacting my application.

In an effort to detect the culprit process(es) I want to monitor CPU usage from within my application, and report when processes not related to my application spike. My Python application uses multiprocessing, and I can establish the PID of all its children processes to filter these from triggering. However accessing the PID of the helper process that's created when I run  `manager=multiprocessing.Manager()` requires me to use `manager._process.pid()` and I'm hesitant to rely on internal attributes.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, why not implement a remote call which returns ```os.getpid()``` in the child process?